# Excel concatenate fuction for whole column

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I need a solution for this:

```
A     B
1.    1,2,3,4,5,,,
2.
3.
4.
5.
```

so i want to concatenate A column like this:

```
(A2;",";A3;",";A4;",";A5;",";A6;",";A7;","; and so on)
```

I want to remove commas (,) behind the number if they're less column - for example 5 and i concatenate 7.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there might be a better way of doing this but i will share my "dumb" way anyway.

In B1 i will make it `= A1`
In B2 `=SUBSTITUTE(B1&","&A2,".","")`
and i just need to fill down the column to the last row

you can get your final result at column B, last row
This is to prevent repetitive selecting all the cells in the whole list (using concatenate)

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `CONCATENATE` as you said. You also can repeat that concatenate with the mouse for all rows.

```
=CONCATENATE(A2, ", ", A3) or =A2 & ", " & A3
```

For more information check this website:

[Concatenate cells with a space, comma and other characters](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/07/15/excel-concatenate-strings-cells-columns/#concatenate-cells-space)

Answer (score 0):

I think, i find the simpliest & best solution and it's a vba code:

```
Function CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(Ref As Range, Separator As String) As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Result As String
For Each Cell In Ref
Result = Result & Cell.Value & Separator
Next Cell
CONCATENATEMULTIPLE = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
End Function
```

Function: =CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(RANGE; ",")

[CONCATENATE Excel Ranges (Using VBA)](https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/)